# Dos script works fine on one machine and not on others, why?

Tags: batch-file

Being not so good in dos-script but have good use for it, I did find here many easy solutions for issues I encounter.
So recently I copied a script form here to count the number of files in subdirectories.
I slightly modified it to suit my purpose. It now is as follows and works fine on my desktop where I composed it:

```
FOR /D %%D IN ("*") DO (
  FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
    ECHO %%D: %%K
  )
)
```

Now the strange part: on my computer (the one the script was made on) the output is as is expected, on other computers the counter doesn't count and gives zero as result (which is absolutely wrong).

All machines are running Windows 7 (professional on the one that counts, the two others use premium resp professional).

What is happening here and how do I correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work here. Suggest you read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same approach

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%a in (*) do for /f "tokens=1,5" %%b in ('
        dir /a-d "%%~fa\*" 2^> nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  " ^|^| echo 0
    ') do if "%%c"=="" echo %%~fa : %%b
```

This will

- For each folder (`for /d`) grab a reference and store it in `%%a` replaceable parameter
- Run a `dir` command with the full path of the folder `%%~fa`
- Use a pipe (`|`) to filter the list to only retrieve the lines that start with two spaces (the footer lines)
- If no lines are found (that is, the `dir` command failed) output a 0
- The lines generated by the `dir | findstr` is handled with a `for /f` command. We will read the first token (the number of files in the adecuated line) and the fifth (only present in the footer line with the directories info)
- If the fifth element is empty, this line has information about the files, not the folders, so, echo the folder path and the files inside it

The problem with this approach is that the `dir | findstr` is executed for each of the subfolders. For a faster solution

```dos
robocopy . . /l /nocopy /is /e /nfl /lev:2 /njh /njs
```

This will simply call `robocopy`, but instead of copying anything, we will request that nothing will be copied and only return the list of what should be processed (`/nocopy /l`). We request to copy from the current folder to the current folder, including identical files in the process (`/is`), processing empty subfolder (`/e`, to include folders with 0 files), but only process two levels (`/lev:2` the current folder and the one below), without generating a file list (`/nfl`), no job header (`/njh`) and no job summary (`/njs`)

The result will be the same list but with the folder name and the number of files in changed columns

To keep the original output format

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy . . /l /nocopy /is /e /nfl /lev:2 /njh /njs
    ') do echo %%~fb : %%a
```

This will use a `for /f` to process the previous `robocopy` command, splitting the line in two tokens, the first will contain the number of files and will be stored in `%%a`, and the second the rest of the line and will be stored in `%%b`. For each line in the output of the inner `robocopy` command, the code in the `do` clause is executed: just echo to console the two tokens in reverse order.

Comment: This typeof complex Dos command line batch script is still abracadabra. I really cannot understand see the difference between the one and the other.
The first two work on all machines, that's for me the mot important.
For robocopy: very usefull way of using it, although again not comprehensible, even after checkin all parameters in the usermanual.

Comment: @jaap, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Installed or changed [Windows display language](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-or-change-a-display-language). Your script is language dependent. For instance, `dir` command shows statistics as `Soubor(ů)` instead of `File(s)` on Czech windows.

`dir |find "Files(s)"` then sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to `1`:

> [`FIND`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) will set `%ERRORLEVEL%` as follows:
>
> - `0` String found in at least one of the files;
> - `1` String not found;
> - `2` If any files in the list do not exist or if no files match a wildcard mask. An invalid switch is given.

And note that "File(s)" is a valid folder name; therefore, your script could show

```
==>md "File(s)"

==>D:\bat\SU\935171.bat
a b: 3
File(s): Directory
FooBar: 0
FooFoo: 4
```

Comment: Sorry, don't get what you're trying to explain to me.